# AsyncTask killed by android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have AsyncTask class that download APK and install it.
During update, there is notfication with progress bar that indicates the progress state.
Additionally I have a broadcast receiver, that receive BOOT_COMPLETE event. The receiver call the AsyncTask.
The problem is, the progress is killed. The notification is displayed, but the progress bar stuck.
Note that, when I call AsyncTask from activity, it works well. It killed only from recevier, in some devices.
Please help! thanks.

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg arg0: String): Boolean {

    try {
        val url = URL(Globals.NEW_APK_URL)
        val c = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        var work = 0
        c.setRequestMethod("GET")
        c.setDoOutput(true)
        c.connect()
        length = c.getHeaderFields().get("content-Length")?.get(0)?.toInt() ?: 0

        val PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/Download/"
        val file = File(PATH)
        file.mkdirs()
        val outputFile = File(file, "update.apk")
        if (outputFile.exists()) {
            outputFile.delete()
        }
        val fos = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

        val `is` = c.getInputStream()

        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var len1 = `is`.read(buffer)
        while (len1 != -1) {
            fos.write(buffer, 0, len1)
            len1 = `is`.read(buffer)
            work += len1
            publishProgress(work)
        }
        fos.close()
        `is`.close()

        val command  = "pm install -r /mnt/sdcard/Download/update.apk"
        val proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("su", "-c", command))
        proc.waitFor()
        return true


    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("UpdateAPP", "Update error! " + e.message)
    }

    return false
}

override fun onPostExecute(result: Boolean) {
    super.onPostExecute(result)
    if (result == true) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "לוח ניסן עודכן בהצלחה", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        context.startActivity(Intent(context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(Globals.PACKAGE_NAME)))
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "העדכון נכשל", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager?
    notificationManager!!.cancelAll()
}

override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: Int?) {
    //Update progress bar
    super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
    runner?.run(values[0] as Any, length)

}
```

Comment: I'm happy to hear that Android kills the attempt of an application randomly fetching a new APK version after restarting my phone that it tries to force me to use to update itself, independently from the play store or any other controlled mechanism...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broadcast receivers are not intended for long-running background work, and the system will tend to kill them shortly after the `onReceive()` function returns. The Android developer guides have some [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#effects-process-state) on this behavior.

It's probably better to use a foreground service for this, especially since you already have a notification anyway.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I need support API 23 and 'run in foreground' became avaiable only from API 26.